# Inserción de datos UNIQUEIDENTIFIER en una tabla Relacional

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, interfaz-gráfica

Quiero pasarle los datos de la tabla1 a otra que se llama principal, donde en ésta contengo una llave foránea, pero en la Tabla1 tengo un Id de tipo Uniqueidentifier y necesito ese valor en la tabla principal porque por medio de ese dato obtengo un nombre. Quiero decir que la tabla1 es una tabla relacional y dependiente de la principal y es ahí donde necesito ese dato. Cómo hago para obtener ese id en un procedimiento almacenado en sql server e insertarlo en la tabla principal? 
[image: Algo Así:]

Comment: Por qué estás usando un SELECT para regresar el valor que ya tienes en la variable?

Comment: Podrías poner el código como texto en vez de ponerlo como imagen?

Comment: Si uso directamente el insert en el procedimiento almacenado, me arroja un error al insertar un valor id de otra tabla como tipo de datos uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Necesitas poner la definición de la Tabla_Ppal y poner el código como texto en vez de imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Era simple, de acuerdo contigo Luis Cazares, no es necesario un select, basta con el insert y si los parámetros de los datos uniqueidentifier pertenecientes a las tablas anteriores, sólo que a la hora de insertar los datos adquiridos de las tablas anteriores (Id's de tipo UniqueIdentifier) era entre comillas simples " '' ". Gracias por su interés. Saludos